# Showing shopify shipping rates based on weekday

Tags: shopify

I have a question. How can I show certain shipping rates, based on a weekday in shopify checkout. For instance, I would like shopify to show different shipping rates on weekends, which are more expensive.

I know it should be something like this pseudocode:

```
Get current day of week
If day equal to Saturday and Sunday

{show these weekend shipping methods}

else

{show regular shipping methods}
```

Can anyone help me with the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically what we have done for a decade or so is install a custom carrier service for that purpose. By doing that, Shopify sends your App the origin, destination, and payload, to which you respond with JSON about pricing. So you get to take into account the number of days to delivery, the service levels, and how much to charge, based on delivery being a weekday or weekend.

It maybe different in 2022, but I kind of doubt it, so if you indeed control your own Shipping Rates and service levels, and want to present better numbers to customers, just put a custom carrier service into play.